# Como iterar este objeto de javascript en C# (o la forma correcta de enviar con AJAX) en ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

A partir de una tabla donde el usuario puede agregar, eliminar y modificar sus valores, se obtiene un tipo de dato como el que se muestra abajo (el cual no puedo modificar su formato o tipo de dato) [[aquí el código de la tabla](https://codepen.io/wanderlp/pen/rVQEmo) ]:

```
var info = [{
            nombres: 'Juan',
            apellidos: 'Pérez',
            email: 'juanperez@gmail.com',
            pass: '123juan'
        }, {
                nombres: 'Julio',
                apellidos: 'López',
                email: 'jlopez@gmail.com',
                pass: 'passjulio'
        }];
```

Pero del lado del servidor, se obtiene desde Request.Params, al depurar y ver los valores que se obtienen del post, en vez de llegar la lista anterior como un arreglo u objeto, llega cada valor por separado, lo cual hace complejo su iteración para luego guardarlos en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del controlador:

```
public JsonResult MiAction()
    { var x = Request.Params["info[]"];
        return Json("ok");
    }
```

Y este es el formulario y el script:

```
function enviar_usuarios() {
       var info = [{
            nombres: 'Juan',
            apellidos: 'Pérez',
            email: 'juanperez@gmail.com',
            pass: '123juan'
        }, {
                nombres: 'Julio',
                apellidos: 'López',
                email: 'jlopez@gmail.com',
                pass: 'passjulio'
            }];
        var info2=[];
        info2[1] = info;
        $.ajax({
            data: { "info": info2 }, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url: '/Home/MiAction', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type: 'post', //método de envio

            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    }

<input type="button" onclick="enviar_usuarios()" id="btn" value="Ir">
```

Y esto ultimo son algunos intentos de solución que no han funcionado a partir de la siguiente variable

```
var info = [{
                nombres: 'Juan',
                apellidos: 'Pérez',
                email: 'juanperez@gmail.com',
                pass: '123juan'
            }, {
                    nombres: 'Julio',
                    apellidos: 'López',
                    email: 'jlopez@gmail.com',
                    pass: 'passjulio'
           }];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("lista", lista_JSON);

var formData = {"lista": lista_JSON, "lista2": [lista_JSON], "lista3": {lista_JSON}};

var formData = { lista: lista_JSON};
```

Comment: Hola Alex, creo que en el script no estás enviando bien los datos prueba cambiando: 
data: { "info": info2 }, por  : JSON.stringify({ "info": info2  }), y agregando: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viendo la estructura de tu Json puedes declararte una clase de la siguiente forma

```
public class Info
{
    public string nombres { get; set; }
    public string apellidos { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
}
```

Luego en la acción de tu controlador definir así la firma

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MiAction(IEnumerable<Info> request)
{ 
    var info1 = request[0]; // primer elemento 
    return Json("ok");
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya tengo la clase, intentaré lo de la acción

Answer (score 0):

Así sería según lo que te comenté:

```
function enviar_usuarios() {
       var info = [{
            nombres: 'Juan',
            apellidos: 'Pérez',
            email: 'juanperez@gmail.com',
            pass: '123juan'
        }, {
                nombres: 'Julio',
                apellidos: 'López',
                email: 'jlopez@gmail.com',
                pass: 'passjulio'
            }];
        var info2=[];
        info2[1] = info;
        $.ajax({
             JSON.stringify({ "info": info2 }), //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
           dataType: "json", 
            url: '/Home/MiAction', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type: 'post', //método de envio

            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: al agregar contentType y type, no enviaba nada.

Answer (score 0):

AL final, de acuerdo a las respuestas de Sergio Parra y Eduardo Valenzuela, dentro del AJAX se modifico la linea del DATA y el action se agregó más código para leer y almacenar ese JSON, y quedó así:

```js
    function enviar_usuarios() {
        var info = [{
            nombres: 'Juan',
            apellidos: 'Pérez',
            email: 'juanperez@gmail.com',
            pass: '123juan'
        }, {
            nombres: 'Julio',
            apellidos: 'López',
            email: 'jlopez@gmail.com',
            pass: 'passjulio'
        }];
        var info2 = [];
        info2[1] = info;
        $.ajax({
            data: { 'info': JSON.stringify({ 'info': info } ) }, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url: '/Home/MiAction', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type: 'post', //método de envio
            
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="enviar_usuarios()" id="btn" value="Ir" />
```

Y dentro del controlador, la acción y clase que almacenará la info recibida quedaría:

```
 public class Usuarios
{
    public string nombres { get; set; }
    public string apellidos { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult MiAction()
    {


        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(Request.Params["info"]));
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Valor: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
            }
        }

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(Request.Params["info"]);
        // Obtener la propiedades result en una lista 
        IList<JToken> results = jObject["info"].Children().ToList();
        // Serializa resultados JSON a un objeto.NET
        IList<Usuarios> searchResults = new List<Usuarios>();

        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            Usuarios searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Usuarios>(result.ToString());
            searchResults.Add(searchResult);
        }

        // Lista las propiedades del resultado de la busqueda (IList)
        foreach (Usuarios item in searchResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.nombres);
            Console.WriteLine(item.apellidos);
            Console.WriteLine(item.email);
            Console.WriteLine(item.pass);
        }

        return Json("ok");
    }
```